# How to use javascript class globaly in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have some Validator class for all forms in my nuxt app, now I am trying to use that Validator class globally instead of importing it to every, almost every page on my app.

Since I saved `Validator` class with plugins with importing I am using it like this:

```
import Validator from '@/plugins/validator.js/
...
data () {
  return {
    formOne: new Validator({
      fieldOne: '',
      fieldTwo: 'gender',
      fieldMillion: []
    })
  }
}
```

Then I use `if(!this.form.validate(this.validationRules)) //do stuff`

But could I somehow use this `Validator` class globally?

I tried importing Vue and using `Vue.use(Validator)` but it needs `new` because of constructor and when I add new then I cannot create new Object and all methods fail..

Inside I have:

```
class Validator {
....
}
export default Validator
```

Comment: The part where you import it should be a plugin, and then you can register it in nuxt-config.js

Comment: Read my question or give dummy sandbox working example